# How to use elasticsearch distance query with more than one geopoint

Tags: elasticsearch

Say, I want to search for a document which is within 5kms of any of the three geo points A,B or C. Is it possible to do it within a single query or how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use a `bool/should` query with three `geo_distance` queries.

```
POST /your_index/_yearch
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "geo_distance": {
            "distance": "5km",
            "pin.location": {
              "lat": 40,
              "lon": -70
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "geo_distance": {
            "distance": "5km",
            "pin.location": {
              "lat": 41,
              "lon": -71
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "geo_distance": {
            "distance": "5km",
            "pin.location": {
              "lat": 42,
              "lon": -72
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```